# Android studio - invisible button

Tags: android, button, android-studio, invisible

I'm trying to make an invisible button in android studio, but i have a problem. When i click on the button it turns orange as long as I hold it and I want to remove that so that the button is always invisible. I used this to make the button invisible: ?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle. Please help, I looked everywhere but I couldn't find the solution. I'm a newbie at this so please make the explanation as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Show your borderlessButtonStyle file. and show me your layout.xml

Comment: You can set it's visibility to GONE, or try to set it's background to @android:color/transparent

Comment: android:visibility="gone" write this line in your button layout.

Comment: When I set the visibility to gon or invisible the button doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create selector under drawable folder and set color or image over there for different sates of the button.

I have created one sample application for you and am pasting code snippet:

Code for button_selector.xml that contains selector code for button which you will need to put under drawable folder:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/no_box_selector" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/no_box"></item>
```

You will need to put no_box_selector and no_box pngs in drawable-hdpi or any drawable folders

Code for activity_main.xml that will be your main xml that contains only one button as of now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relRingtone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try implementing these things and let me know if you need any further assisstance.....

All the best!!!

Reference : [Disable pressed background color of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227827/disable-pressed-background-color-of-button)

Answer (score 0):

android:visibility="gone" or android:visibility="invisible", this will remove your button from layout.

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="submit"
android:visibility="gone"
></Button>
```

Comment: When I set the visibility to gone or invisible the button doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hapus"
        android:background="#a41a1a"
        android:id="@+id/btnhapus"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

**android:visibility="gone"** for invisibility button, and **android:visibility="visible"** for visible button